# How show a static number of rows using Ag datagrid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm new on reactjs, and I want to create a table to show some data. In the project I'm working, we are using Ag-Grid datagrid.

I already have created it with basic usage, but my question is:

Supose I have 100 rows as enter, how I can display in datagrid just the 10 firsts?

I stil wanna load all data (for filtering, sort, etc), just don't wanna show all by default.

I'm looking at [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/) and do some search, but don't find the proper way to do it.

Edit: I already see the pagination options (the default solution provided by documentation), but in my case, at least for now I don't want pagination. Just wanna render the X first rows (the extra will be ommited in table, but have to be loaded in UI, if not, I could use autoHeight).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using the [Client Side Row Model](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/client-side-model/) and not loading data from a Server. In which case, the easiest way to achieve this would be to show the 10 rows, and add more rows (depending on when you want to load them) via Transaction Updates, please see the [documentation on this here](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/data-update-transactions/)

Comment: Thanks man, I saw this option, but in my case I can't show pagination.
I just wanna get all data and render the X firsts, but without pagination (at least for now).
I'll edit my question for be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pagination:
[documentation reference](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/row-pagination/#example-auto-page-size)

Comment: Thanks man, I saw this option, but in my case I can't show pagination.
I just wanna get all data and render the X firsts, but without pagination (at least for now).
I'll edit my question for be more precise.

Comment: If that's the case, and I see in your updatge that you want to also show the rest of the data, you should parse that data array on your javascript/typescript that you are writing your logic. pass only the data you need to the grid and use the rest for the extra table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Since my question I start to think in a second table (is your suggestion, right? or I missunderstd?), but is like a plan B, because mainly, goal is receive all data, in a first step show X rows, and have a button to expand datagrid (now with all rows). So, if I have other table, I have to custom a lot, is easier if I can just have a datagrid showing X rows and with some function refresh it changing the limit of rows.

Comment: Ya, but what I'm suggesting is just have two arrays of data. One for the x first and another for the rest. then you can render them any way you want.

Comment: Oh, you mean instead of receive one array, receive two, show the first one (x lines), and when user change something, like a button, call datagrid again, but now with the second array. I understood properly?
Is a good idea, really. I'll look if is possible in the context I have here.